# docker-compose healthcheck does not work in a way it is expected for making container a run first and then container B

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to run couple of service which depends on each other. Here is part of the docker-compose:

```
  backend:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "npm run build && npm start"
    ports: 
      - "3015:3015"
    depends_on:
      - couchdb
      - redis
      - uds-mock-server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    user: root
  api-test:
    restart: always 
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3015/readiness"]
      interval: 200s
      timeout: 200s
      retries: 5
    user: root
```

As you see I have two service over there and backend should first run and the server needs to be ready then api-test can start. backend has an endpoint: localhost:2015/readiness and whenever it returns 200 then api test can start. When I run while building the order is respected so backend first followed by api-mock but when docker compose starts running them api-test run quicker and since it relies on the backend to be ready it fails.

Base on the following:

[Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y/41854997#41854997)

and

[Docker healthcheck in composer file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895558/docker-healthcheck-in-composer-file?rq=1)

It is suggested that I should use healthcheck which I do in api test:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3015/readiness"]
  interval: 200s
  timeout: 200s
  retries: 5
```

If I get this correctly api-test should run and call the readiness endpoint and wait until it hears from backend readiness (up to 200s) if it fails it waits for 200s and then try again for 5 times. 
But what I see is api-test keep failing and restarting and does not even give a chance to backend to run and it keeps doing this like a loop.
Am I missing anything? Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The two examples are based on the `condition` form of [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) which is no longer supported in compose version 3. So, unless your docker-compose version is <3 the `healthcheck` will not help you much. The `healthcheck` sets the status of the container (*starting, healthy or unhealthy*) but `docker-compose` does not wait until `backend` container is healthy before starting the `app-test`. There is a detailed explanation about how `depends_on` works in [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

As a side note, the healthcheck in your compose file sets the status of the `app-test` container and not `backend`.

Therefore to control when the `api-test` can start, you have to wrap the service command of the container. For your particular case the following will do the job:

```
bash -c 'while [[ "$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://backend:3015/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up; <service_command>'
```

It tries to connect to `backend` every 5 seconds (the connection timeout is 2s). When the received HTTP status code is 200 OK the loop ends and it executes the `<service_command>`

The relevant docker-compose part:

```
  api-test:
    restart: always
    command: bash -c 'while [[ "$$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' uds-mock-server:4000/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up;npm start'
    depends_on:
      - backend
      ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I run your command I get this: ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "de-backend": "bash -c 'while [[ "$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://uds-mock-server:4000/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up; npm start'"

Comment: @Learner In the docker-compose.yml file you should escape the `$` with another `$`. See [Variable Substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution). I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That worked but when I run the compose I see the api-test service keeps sending .. though readiness is readiness is ready with 200 it seems to be an infinite loop so this never happens echo backend is up; npm start

Comment: What do you get if you run `curl -v uds-mock-server:4000/readiness` inside the api-test container? Is the uds-mock-server the service you wish to check is ready?

Comment: Yes it is mock-server. I changed the code a bit because of requirements changes

Comment: when I echo the condition: "$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://backend:3015/readiness)" I get this 000

Comment: Try to run curl in verbose mode to see what's going on.

Comment: getting this
backend_1       | *   Trying xxxx...
backend_1       | * TCP_NODELAY set
backend_1       | * connect to xxx port 4000 failed: Connection refused
backend_1       | * Failed to connect to mock-server port 4000: Connection refused
backend_1       | * Closing connection 0
backend_1       | .. [000]

Comment: ooops my bad http not https Thanks

Comment: docker supports clean health checks. No need to hack something together.

Comment: @b0gusb the statement "healthcheck will not help you much" is no longer true https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-1

Answer (score 23):

it's not `localhost` connection string.

It should be service name of backend container :

```
test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://backend:3015/readiness"]
```

Comment: This one fixed it for me!

Comment: is there any way to use semicolon in statement? for example: test: ["CMD", "netstat", "-an | grep 45800 > /dev/null; if [ 0 != $? ]; then exit 1; fi;"]
It gives an error to me: 
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "healthcheck" option in service "frontend": "-an | grep 45800 > /dev/null; if [ 0 != $? ]; then exit 1; fi;"

Comment: This solved it for the, but what does the "-f" flag do?

Comment: @Beyar the "-f" flag ignores any error HTTP response that may be returned from the server. Instead it'll just return error 22 code (you can read more about it in the man page)

Comment: `healthcheck` should not test foreign container. It is designed to check current container.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the latest Docker Desktop (tested on Windows with version 4.14.0) then use [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) with `condition: service_healthy`.  Example:

```
    depends_on:
      oracle:
        condition: service_healthy
```

**Note**: the version of compose is confusing.   Over the years `docker-compose` became `docker compose` and [alternate implementations](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-v2/) were introduced with overlapping version numbers.  The version that ships with Docker Desktop now appears to be called [docker compose V2](https://github.com/docker/compose), which you indicate in your docker-compose.yml file by [NOT including any version number](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#version-top-level-element).  This differs from the [legacy docker-compose V2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/), which actually defaults to docker-compose V1 if no version is specified in the YAML file.